# HTML Input Button with Subscript

Tags: html, css, format, subscript

How can I format a typical Input with `type="button"` to display content text having a subscript format?

Example: O<sub>2</sub>

Answer (score 1):

### See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dpwdhk2k/)

You can use HTML `<sub>` to insert subscript. See the below given HTML

**HTML**

```
<button type="button">
  O<sub>2</sub>
</button>
```

Read more about `<sub>` in the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/sub)

Answer (score 1):

For that particular example you could just use Unicode [code point U+2082](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2082/index.htm):

```html
    <input type="button" value="O₂">
```

… but in the general case the solution is stop using an input. HTML 4 introduced the `<button>` element to replace the submit, button and reset types.

`<button>` has two main advantages:

- The value and display content can be different
- The display content can include markup

```html
<button type="button"> O<sub>2</sub> </button>
```

Comment: Thank you @Lal & Quentin.  I spent the afternoon exploring all sorts of options and did indeed move to using <Button type=Button> for better flexibility.  Interestingly, the O<sub>2</sub> has an odd behavior onkeydown: The "O" moves but the "2" remains static.  Therefore the Entity ID (whether Unicode or HTML) actually works better.  In addition, I experimented further with the innerHTML to include Font Awesome compilations with great success.  Quirky fun :)